# Laptop suspends automatically

Tags: boot, system

I've installed elementary OS on a laptop and it's suspending automatically every 20 seconds. Someone have an idea of how can i resolve this? I can't even start the os, during boot, it suspends.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on AC? if you are on DC, is your battery having some issues?